Blazor Web App NET 8-Pass Access Token to SignalR Endpoint
My Blazor backend app uses a custom AuthenticationStateProvider which persists the authenticated user on both the backend app and the web assembly client app. I can use a BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler when registering an http client which will attach my access token to header, however the SignalR JavaScript client uses WebSockets and I have to attach the access token to the query string. How do I get the access token in a razor component inside my web assembly client app? The cascaded parameter AuthenticationState, HttpContext or the HttpContextAcessor objects do not have it and I read it's not even safe to use the HttpConext in a razor component. the MS documentation here: blazor8 doesn't help. This is where I'm stuck:
    hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
.WithUrl(Navigation.ToAbsoluteUri("https://localhost:7288/chathub"), options =>
{
    options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(signalRToken);
    options.Headers.Add("BusinessId", MapInitialization!.BusinessId!.Value!.ToString());
    options.Headers.Add("BusinessRole", MapInitialization?.SignalRRole!);
    options.Headers.Add("DisplayName", MapInitialization?.SignalRDisplayName!);
    options.Headers.Add("UserName", MapInitialization?.SignalRUserName!);               

}).Build();

I've tried injecting the IHttpContextAccessor into my AuthenticationStateProvider class but I can't seem to find the access token:
public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
{
    if (authenticationStateTask == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Do not call {nameof(GetAuthenticationStateAsync)} outside of the DI scope for a Razor component. Typically, this means you can call it only within a Razor component or inside another DI service that is resolved for a Razor component.");
    }
    ...
}

I've also tried setting the HttpContext properties with the OnSignedIn callback inside the CookieAuthenticationOptions class from the CookieSignedIn properties but it wasn't persisting:
cookieOptions.Events.OnSignedIn = context =>
{
    var http = context.HttpContext;
    http.Items["Properties"] = context.Properties;
    http.Features.Set(context.Properties);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
};

Can I get the access token in my web assembly client app razor pages to pass into my query string?

Could you kindly check this official doc?

Setup isn't the issue. The issue is how do you obtain your access token inside your cookie in a blazor web assembly app component.

Could you kindly check this answer?

WebAssemblies use IAccessTokenProvider. I'm using a web app which persists differently so it uses a different token provider middleware.

Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62074612/blazor-webassembly-signalr-authentication

Same thing, uses IAccessTokenProvider

How to persist tokens in a CustomAuthenticationStateProvider: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62529029/customizing-the-authenticationstateprovider-in-blazor-server-app-with-jwt-token

Saving and Retrieving Access Token in a Blazor WebApp: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59891352/how-do-i-get-the-access-token-from-a-blazor-server-side-web-app
